# Conflicting result for velocity and radius in physiology

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, flow, biophysics

My problem is that we say V = Q/A (V velocity, Q flow, and A area of pipe) in haemodynamics. Based on this formula, the velocity ​​is inversely related to the second power of the radius. Combining this with [Poiseuille’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation) (Q = π⋅r⁴⋅P / 8⋅η⋅l) to find velocity, we get this result:

> ”The velocity has a direct relationship with the second power of the radius”.

Why does this give a different result? In Guyton’s *Physiology* it says

> “By integrating the velocities of all the concentric rings of flowing blood and multiplying them by the areas of the rings, one can derive the following formula, known as Poiseuille’s law”

which means these two formulae are related to each other. What is wrong with my calculations?

At first I thought that with increase in radius we will have a decrease in velocity, but then I find in Poiseuille’s law it was vice versa.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1. What is Q in your first equation? 2. what area is A in this equation?

Comment: Different from what?  Which two formulae?  what calculation?

Answer (score 4):

When you conclude from $V=Q / A$ that $V$ is proportional to $r^{-2}$ you are implicitly assuming that $Q$ is independent of $A$ and $r$, which is incorrect.

Poiseuille’s law tells us that $Q$ is proportional to $r^4$. So $V$ is proportional to $r^4 / A$, and hence $V$ is proportional to $r^2$.